# Comma Separated string to separate value in array c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an array of 2 attributed model in asp.net mvc c#.

```
str  |ID
s1,s2|1
s3   |2
s4,s5|3
```

I want to separate it into a separate string array

```
str|ID
s1 |1
s2 |1
s3 |2
s4 |3
s5 |3
```

Can anyone have idea, how to do it in one line instead of for loop?

Comment: Why do you need to use one line instead of a for loop?

Comment: Please, post a MCVE and what you have tried so far. Currently we don't even know how this is stored, is it a List<(string,int)>, a dictionary, a multidimensional object array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq` to get expected Result, like the following code:

1 - i'm creating a class for test:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Str { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

2 - using `Split` and `SelectMany` functions, without loop:

```
var array = new Test[] { new Test { Str = "s1,s2", ID = 1 }, new Test { Str = "s3", ID = 2 }, new Test { Str = "s4,s5", ID = 3 } };

var newArray = array
    .SelectMany(x => x.Str.Split(',').Select(y => new Test { Str = y, ID = x.ID }))
    .ToArray();
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way

```
void Main()
{
    List<Original> originals = new List<Original>();
    originals.Add(new Original { Str = "str1,str2", Id = 1 });
    originals.Add(new Original { Str = "str3", Id = 2 });
    originals.Add(new Original { Str = "str4,str5", Id = 3 });
    originals.Add(new Original { Str = "str6", Id = 4 });

    List<Original> splitted = new List<Original>();
    splitted = originals.Select(x => new { Strs = x.Str.Split(',') , Id = x.Id }).SelectMany(y => y.Strs.Select(z => new Original { Str = z, Id = y.Id})).ToList();

    foreach(var t in splitted)
    Console.WriteLine(t.Str + " " + t.Id);
}


class Original
{
    public string Str { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```